# Similar domain redirects

Tags: redirect, https, dns

Hoping somebody will be able to help me to understand how the following would work as well as why it would need to be done if that's okay?

I've got two domains.

1. domain-one.co.uk - this is the main domain and holds an SSL cert
2. domain-one-uk.com - this is another domain our client owns, it's not secure and they want it to redirect to the first domain.

Is this simply going to be a case of adding a 301 rule in the htaccess file in the public folder or do I need to do anything with the DNS settings?

I added the following but it didn't seem to work

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\-one\-uk\.com$
RewriteRule ^$ https://www.domain-one.co.uk/? [L,R=301]
```

Would appreciate any help and teaching anyone can provide.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If there is no existing URLs to redirect and this is only a domain redirect, i'd go for a basic 301 redirect in the .htaccess on the insecure server, which will redirect anything that arrives there to the new domain :

```
Redirect 301 / https://secure-domain.net/
```

If the insecure server used to have content that is also available on the secure server (with the same URLs, besides the protocol and domain), then you indeed need to use RewriteRules, eg. :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

In your case, the missing "RewriteEngine On" certainly caused the redirect not to work.

The RewriteCond that checks the current domain name is only needed if this htaccess is used by both domains (ie. they are handled by the same server, using the same directory).